# htaccess file not redirecting a certain url

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I added an SSL to my site and have the following htaccess file in place to redirect:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS}        =off   [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^example\.com$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$          "https://example.com/$1" [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
```

This covers almost everything, so http://www.example.com, http://example.com, and example.com all forward to https://example.com. However, there is one scenario where it does not. If I enter https://www.example.com, it does not redirect to https://example.com and I get a security certificate error. Looking for a solution. Thank you in advance.

cdr6545

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymlinks
  # To redirect from www to non www (Rewrite www.example.com → example.com)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http%{ENV:protossl}://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

  # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS automatically (only if not in localhost)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```